# Merging unevaluated key/values

Tags: syntax, associations, hold

`RuleDelayed` is a supported key/value wrapper in `Associations`.

What are general guidelines/idiomatic methods for working with such associations?

Specifically, how to `Merge` them:

```
ds = { 
  <|a :> Print[1], b -> 2|>
, <|a :> Print[2], b :> 1 + 1|>
};

Merge[Last] @ ds
```

> ```
> <|a :> Last[{Print[1], Print[2]}], b :> Last[{2, 1 + 1}]|>
> ```

For `Merge[Last]` case we can replace it with `Association`:

```
Association @ ds
```

> ```
> <|a :> Print[2], b :> 1 + 1|>
> ```

But that is not general enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure that it qualifies as a general idiom, but here is one way to address this specific case.  First, we define a helper function that evaluates the right-hand side of a `RuleDelayed` expression:

```
evalRhs[k_ :> v_] := k :> # &[v]
```

Then we use that function to evaluate the `Last` expressions that become embedded within an intermediate association object by the `Merge`:

```
ds // Query[Merge[Last] /* AssociationMap[evalRhs], All, Unevaluated]
```

`Unevaluated` is applied to the individual key values to ensure that they maintain their unevaluated forms while the `Last` expression is evaluated.  `evalRhs` will see expressions of the form:

```
key :> Last[{Unevaluated[value1], Unevaluated[value2], ...}]
```

By construction, the outer `Last` and `List` functions will be applied and then the remaining `Unevaluated` heads will be stripped in the calls to `RuleDelayed`.

Here is an extract from a trace of the evaluation, showing some key steps:

[image: stack trace screenshot]

**General Strategy**

Even though this solution is designed for the specific case at hand, we can extract a general strategy:

- Apply the desired operator to the `RuleDelayed` key-values pairs (in this case, `Merge[Last])`.
- Accept the fact that this will create an intermediate association with more complicated unevaluated expressions as values.
- Perform selective evaluation of the values within the intermediate association.
- Implement the selective evaluation using pattern-matching and evaluation control constructs.  The exact form of that selective evaluation will need to be crafted to account for the operator that was initially applied and the desired results.
- Accept the fact that selective evaluation control is a messy business generally, and doubly-so within associations :)

Comment: One thing I tend to use is a tagging Head that evaluates as Identity. Then I use ReplaceAll with that to do what I want with that tag. That avoids the RHS ballooning in complexity.